# Merge two tabel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables. I need to merge two tables with `cx1`, `cx2` and `Date` keys. How is it?

```
fist table
cx1   Date       Amount
1     11/1/2019   400
1     12/1/2019   200
2     15/1/2019   400
3     16/1/2019   500
```

```
Second Table
cx2    Date        Amount
1      11/1/2019   300
2      16/1/2019   200
3      16/1/2019   400
```

```
Final output
cx     Date        Amount_1    Amount_2
1      11/1/2019   400         300
1      12/1/2019   0           300
2      15/1/2019   400         0
2      16/1/2019   0           200
3      16/1/2019   500         400
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['cx1'], right_on='cx2', how='left')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I tried this code now but I am getting cx1 and cx2.  I need to get only one column for cx which I mention in final out table

Comment: need to join the group (left - cx1, Date   and right - cx2, Date)

Comment: @ShulazShan Shouldn't the output in row 2 will be `1  12/1/2019     200      0` instead of `1      12/1/2019   0           300`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma can no issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, the combination of [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html), [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), [`Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), [`Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html):

```
df = pd.merge(
    df1.rename(columns={'cx1': 'cx'}), df2.rename(columns={'cx2': 'cx'}),
    on=['cx', 'Date'], how='outer', suffixes=('_1', '_2'))

df = df.sort_values(by='cx').fillna(0)
df[['cx', 'Amount_1', 'Amount_2']] = df[['cx', 'Amount_1', 'Amount_2']].astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   cx       Date  Amount_1  Amount_2
0   1  11/1/2019       400       300
1   1  12/1/2019       200         0
2   2  15/1/2019       400         0
4   2  16/1/2019         0       200
3   3  16/1/2019       500       400
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the concat() method?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series(['a', 'b'])
>>> s2 = pd.Series(['c', 'd'])
>>> pd.concat([s1, s2])
```

Output:

```
0    a
1    b
0    c
1    d
```

dtype: object

Comment: no plz look at my final output, that is i am expecting as final table

Comment: Can you post the sources of the dataframes, e.g. lists, text, etc?

Comment: I have two excel sheet one is customer cash-in and second customer cash-out table. the cash-in table has customer_num, Date, Amount, and second, the cash-out table has customer_num1, Date, Amount. I need to merge those two tables.

Comment: see my final table, that what I am expecting